# Update a single spinner in Android based upon the current value

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

Is it possible to update a spinner based on its current content?

For example, I have a spinner with two values - fruit, vegetables.  If the user selects the vegetables option, the spinner will updates its values, and take the new values from a string array, for example, vegetable array containing values potatoes, carrots, mushrooms, peppers.  My intention is to only use and update one spinner.

Any advice, hints, tutorials or recommendations would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: you can change the array in the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it

Comment: Thanks Android Student :)

Answer (score 0):

What you would have to do would be changing the adapter, whether you switched what adapter was being displayed, or just switching out what lists that adapter was using. Once you have changed the adapter, you notifyDataSetChanged(). I'm not sure how nice that will look graphically, but it should do the trick.